# Unable to get elements from HTML web page

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to populate an HTML web page (http://wasitviewed.com) in C# using Selenium but no matter what i try, it always crashes when I try and find the website elements with the following error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"href"}
```

I'm using the below code:

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.wasitviewed.com/");
    IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("href"));
    query.SendKeys("test");
}
```

[image]

I've also tried using xPath but that also fails.

Is there an easier way to find the elements of the web page or is there a way i can loop through the whole web page to find the different elements and their respective id's?

Comment: I believe the **element** name is **input**. and its **attribute** called **name** has a value of **href**

Comment: @MohitShrivastava even if I try using _input_ it still doesn't work and i get the same error" `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"input"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above mentioned URL, all the elements are resides within an iframe. So, you need to move the foucs into the frame before finding the query element,otherwise `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown.

Whenever any element is present inside the iframe, you need to move the foucs to the frame using any one of the below startegy.

**Using Index:**

Index starts frame 0.So, you can switch to the frame using the index as below

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);//Here only one frame is available.so, Index is 0
```

**Using Frame Name or Id:**

Select a frame by its (frame) name or ID.  name attributes are always given precedence over the id attributes.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(<<Frame Name or ID>>);
```

Currently, frame name/id is not available in the mentioned URL.
So, you cannot use the Frame name or ID.

**Using Frame WebElement:**

You need to find the Frame `WebElement` using any one of the Locator strategies `(Name,Id,ClassName,TagName,XPath,CssSelector`)
and it can be used to move the foucs to the respective frame.

```
//Here only one frame is available.So, I have used FindElement
var frameElement= driver.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameElement);
```

**Working Code:**

**Option 1 :**

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.wasitviewed.com/");
    driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);
    IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("href"));
    query.SendKeys("test");
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.wasitviewed.com/");
    var frameElement= driver.FindElement(By.TagName("iframe"));
    driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameElement);
    IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("href"));
    query.SendKeys("test");
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you @Subburaj the detailed reply. That works perfectly. So I've managed to now set all the fields I need to but I can't seem to get the _shortenedLink_ value. The code I am using is this: `var shortenedLink = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='results']/p[1]/input")).Text;
                MessageBox.Show(shortenedLink);` **MessageBox** always shows blank. I am using XPath because that field doesn't look to have a _name_ attribute set.

Comment: Whether you are trying to get the value from the input field. If it so, it can't be done using Text Method and the same thing can be achieved using `GetAttribute("value")` method. Change the code as  `var shortenedLink = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='results']/p[1]/input")).GetAttribute("value"); MessageBox.Show(shortenedLink);`

Answer (score 0):

Your required `<input>` element is inside an iframe. You need to switch to that before performing actions on any elements inside the iframe.

```
IWebElement yourIFrame= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(yourIFrame);
```

Now, this should work -

```
IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("href"));
query.SendKeys("test");
```

Also, once you are done dealing with inside iframe, you can switch back to default content by -

```
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

As your element in iframe so first go to iframe then locate the element for functioning

```
IWebElement FirstIFrame= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@src='index.php']"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(FirstIFrame);

//Now perform operations 
 IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("href"));
 query.SendKeys("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question the elements within the url `http://wasitviewed.com/` are within an `<iframe>`. So once you access the *url* first you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `<iframe>` to be *available and switch to it* then you need to induce *WebDriverWait* again for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.wasitviewed.com/");
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.XPath("//iframe[@src='index.php']")));
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@class='inputText' and @name='href']"))).SendKeys("test");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way to get the value of the text field **Shortened Trackable URL** when it doesn't have a name from the same url: [wasitviewed.com](http://wasitviewed.com)? I'm trying with the following code but doesn't seem to return anything. Its just blank. `var shortenedLink = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='results']/p[1]/input")).Text; MessageBox.Show(shortenedLink);`

Comment: @MattList _get the value of the text field **Shortened Trackable URL**_ seems to be a new requirement all together. Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement. Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: @MattList If this, or any other answer, was useful please upvote it for the benefit of the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

btw. when you will be confused with iframe, which iframe you should use to switch, then you can also use something like

```
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

or
`driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());` <-- this switch to the last, this is good in some case, when you are already switched in 2-3 level of iframe and you want to return. I am using with both very often.

both I am using also when I am working with pop up windows.